# Groupby on 2 columns plus filter on String columns

Tags: python, pandas

**Sample DF:**

```
ID   Name        Price     Condition   Fit_Test
1    Apple         10      Good        Super_Fit
2    Apple         10      OK          Super_Fit
3    Apple         10      Bad         Super_Fit
4    Orange        12      Good        Not_Fit
5    Orange        12      OK          Not_Fit
6    Banana        15      OK          Medium_Fit
7    Banana        15      Bad         Medium_Fit
8    Pineapple     25      OK          Medium_Fit
9    Pineapple     25      OK          Medium_Fit
10   Cherry        30      Bad         Medium_Fit
```

**Expected DF:**

```
ID   Name        Price     Condition   Fit_Test
1    Apple         10      Good        Super_Fit
2    Apple         10      OK          Super_Fit
3    Apple         10      Bad         Super_Fit

4    Orange        12      Good        Not_Fit

6    Banana        15      OK          Medium_Fit

8    Pineapple     25      OK          Medium_Fit
9    Pineapple     25      OK          Medium_Fit
10   Cherry        30      Bad         Medium_Fit
```

**Problem Statement:**

I want to `group-by` by `Name` and `Price` and then filter based on `Condition`.

1. If within a `Name` and `Price` All 3 conditions of Good, Bad and OK exist then Keep only Good one and Fit_Test is not `Super_Fit`
2. If within a Name and Price conditions of Good and OK exist then Keep only Good one (Id 4,5 is only ID 4 in expected) and Fit_Test is not `Super_Fit`
3. If within a `Name` and `Price` conditions of Bad and OK exist then Keep only OK one **(Id 6,7 is only ID 6 in expected)** and Fit_Test is not `Super_Fit`
4. If within a `Name` and `Price` conditions of OK and OK exist, Good and Good Exist or just Bad exist then don't do anything then Keep only OK one **(Id 8,9,10 is ID 8,9,10 in expected)** and Fit_Test is not `Super_Fit`

**Update on Answer(s)**

1. The 1st answer and edit for testing works for all the `df` where you don't have a condition of `Fit_Test` column. In this answer the **Expected DF** will not have rows 2 & 3 as also shown in the answer
2. The **Edit for Update** answer works when you need to take another columns which is `Fit_Test` and should only work when the value is not `Super_Fit`.

In both the solutions the Filtering of rows based on `Condition` column and group by of 2 columns is same.

**I found things with filter + group by on the numeric columns but none on the String columns.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Idea is create `set`s for comparing:

```
a = df.join(df.groupby(['Price','Name'])['Condition'].apply(set).rename('m'),
             on=['Price','Name'])['m']
print (a)
0    {Bad, Good, OK}
1    {Bad, Good, OK}
2    {Bad, Good, OK}
3         {Good, OK}
4         {Good, OK}
5          {Bad, OK}
6          {Bad, OK}
7               {OK}
8               {OK}
9              {Bad}
Name: m, dtype: object
```

---

```
m1 = (a == set({'Bad', 'Good', 'OK'})) | (a == set({'Good', 'OK'}))
m2 = a == set({'Bad', 'OK'})
#check if unique value - length of set is 1
m3 = a.str.len() == 1
m4 = df['Condition'] == 'Good'
m5 = df['Condition'] == 'OK'

df = df[(m1 & m4) | (m2 & m5) | m3]
print (df)
   ID       Name  Price Condition
0   1      Apple     10      Good
3   4     Orange     12      Good
5   6     Banana     15        OK
7   8  Pineapple     25        OK
8   9  Pineapple     25        OK
9  10     Cherry     30       Bad
```

EDIT for testing:

For testing is possible use `assign`:

```
print (df.assign(sets=a, m1 = m1, m2=m2, m3=m3, m4=m4, m5=m5, m=m))
   ID       Name  Price Condition             sets     m1     m2     m3  \
0   1      Apple     10      Good  {Bad, Good, OK}   True  False  False   
1   2      Apple     10        OK  {Bad, Good, OK}   True  False  False   
2   3      Apple     10       Bad  {Bad, Good, OK}   True  False  False   
3   4     Orange     12      Good       {Good, OK}   True  False  False   
4   5     Orange     12        OK       {Good, OK}   True  False  False   
5   6     Banana     15        OK        {Bad, OK}  False   True  False   
6   7     Banana     15       Bad        {Bad, OK}  False   True  False   
7   8  Pineapple     25        OK             {OK}  False  False   True   
8   9  Pineapple     25        OK             {OK}  False  False   True   
9  10     Cherry     30       Bad            {Bad}  False  False   True   

      m4     m5      m  
0   True  False   True  
1  False   True  False  
2  False  False  False  
3   True  False   True  
4  False   True  False  
5  False   True   True  
6  False  False  False  
7  False   True   True  
8  False   True   True  
9  False  False   True
```

EDIT for update:

For new condition use:

```
    m6 = df['Fit_Test'] == 'Super_Fit'
    df = df[((m1 & m4) | (m2 & m5) | m3) | m6]
    print (df)
       ID       Name  Price Condition    Fit_Test
    0   1      Apple     10      Good   Super_Fit
    1   2      Apple     10        OK   Super_Fit
    2   3      Apple     10       Bad   Super_Fit
    3   4     Orange     12      Good     Not_Fit
    5   6     Banana     15        OK  Medium_Fit
    7   8  Pineapple     25        OK  Medium_Fit
    8   9  Pineapple     25        OK  Medium_Fit
    9  10     Cherry     30       Bad  Medium_Fit
```

Comment: Will it also take care of the `Good Good` condition

Comment: @RahulAgarwal - yes, because set create `{Good}` and `m3` is `True`

Comment: I am loosing rows where I have just one `OK`. I can see `a` is correct but in `df` I see those rows are not there.

Comment: @RahulAgarwal - so in `a` there are only `{OK}` ? And these rows are removed?

Comment: @RahulAgarwal - for testing is possible use `df = df.assign(test=a)` - it create test column by sets.

Comment: Cool..Thanks!! Just one more thing, lets say I have one more column `Fit_test` and it has 3 values `Super Fit , Medium Fit & Not Fit`. Can I add a condition saying run the above code only when the `Fit_test` column is not `Super_Fit`

Comment: @RahulAgarwal - Can you edit answer? For 100% understanding.

Comment: @RahulAgarwal - I am a bit confused, do you think need `df[df['Fit_Test'] != 'Super_Fit']` for filter all rows by condition? Or need remove all groups where at least one  non `Super_Fit` per groups like `df[(df['Fit_Test'] != 'Super_Fit').groupby([df['Price'],df['Name']]).transfrom('all')]` ?

Comment: So, the answer your provided earlier works fine...just one more condition to it..rather that applying to the whole df we can do it on the rows where per group it has doesn't have any `Super_Fit`. Their can be any group where both `Super_Fit` or `Medium_Fit` exists

Comment: So `df[(m1 & m4) | (m2 & m5) | m3]` changed to `m6 = df['Fit_Test'] != 'Super_Fit'` and `df[((m1 & m4) | (m2 & m5) | m3) & m6]` ?

Comment: @RahulAgarwal - Yes? Not all `Series` ? `print (type(m1))` should be Sereis

Comment: @RahulAgarwal - there is something wrong. Because if `m5 = df['Condition'] == 'OK'` is list and `m6 = df['Fit_Test'] != 'Super_Fit'` is `Series` - logic is same, only columns and comapring value is different.

Comment: so it should be both Series

Comment: @RahulAgarwal - yes, it is not expected output? Get all rows if not `Super_Fit` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190300/discussion-between-rahul-agarwal-and-jezrael).

Comment: @RahulAgarwal - Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have too many conditions (like here it is only 3), the following is an easy workaround:

```
df.loc[df["Condition"] == 'Good',"Condition"] = 3
df.loc[df["Condition"] == 'OK',"Condition"] = 2
df.loc[df["Condition"] == 'Bad',"Condition"] = 1

df = df.groupby(['Name','Price']).max()

df.loc[df["Condition"] == 3] = "Good"
df.loc[df["Condition"] == 2] = "OK"
df.loc[df["Condition"] == 1] = "Bad"
```

Comment: It is deleting rows where I have `Good Good` condition ?

Comment: Yes, if all are Good and OK then I want to keep all of them. Point 4 in my question!!

Comment: Ok.  First of all, no reason for getting upset.

Comment: If it seems like this, I apologize. I am not upset or anything like that. Above all, you are helping me!!